# Is it at all possible to make HTTP requests with the Adobe Photoshop JS SDK?

Tags: api, http, rest, photoshop

I've been looking at the Adobe Photoshop JavaScript Scripting documentation, and have only seen the use of WebSockets for remote communications. I need to implement a plugin that communicates with a backend PHP API written in Laravel.

Does the Photoshop JavaScript SDK allow HTTP requests at all?

Answer (score 0):

I use a modified version of the extendables library to allow Indesign to access data from our local webserver.  I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with photoshop. See extendables.org for the library.

ETA: That link doesn't seem to go anywhere at the moment.  The library itself is available here: https://github.com/stdbrouw/Extendables